# Starting as a sole trader under pre-settled status

Tags: united-kingdom, self-employment, european-union, brexit

I've been in the UK for the past 4 years and I have a pre-settled status.
I am currently an employee but I'm considering switching to freelancing/sole-trading to start working with a company abroad.

1. Am I allowed / Are there any limitations given that I don't have neither a fully settled status nor citizenship?
2. Are there any limitations if as a sole trader I work for an EU company?

Would any potential limitations be lifted if I instead register for a limited company?

Answer (score 3):

If you have pre-settled status, you have employment and self-employment rights that are the same as British citizens:

> You’ll be able to:
>
> - work in the UK
> - [...]

https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/what-settled-and-presettled-status-means

Do make sure that you continue to accumulate [evidence of your UK residence](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/eu-settlement-scheme-evidence-of-uk-residence) while self-employed. Obviously you won't be able to rely on your employment records any more but there are plenty of other things like council tax bills.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your visa status prevents you from working independently in the UK, you can follow the steps to become a sole trader [on this government page](https://www.gov.uk/set-up-self-employed).

It shouldn't matter who your customers are (UK, EU or other).